# Python Connecting scartted information that belongs to the same person

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I've been stuck at this for days now I can't get my head around it.

Lets say I have info:

```
Makaviwe, Coding 4, Code Cap 4, 31 Mar 2021, 02 Apr 2021, No 
Sanele, Coding, Coding, 01 Apr 2021, 29 Apr 2021, Yes
Aphelele, Code, 1, 01 Apr 2021, 03 Apr 2021, No
Sanele, Code, Code Review, 08 Apr 2021, 25 Jun 2021, No
```

This is information in a text file containing a Username, Title of a task, Description of a task, The date the task was issued, Due date of the task, completion status(yes = completed). In that order.

I need to answer these questions and present them in an easy to read manner.

- The total number of users registered users.
- The total number of tasks that have been generated and tracked.

**For each user also describe:**

- The total number of tasks assigned to that user.
- What percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to that user?
- What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have been completed?
- What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user must still be completed?
- What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have not yet been completed and are overdue?

This is how far i was able to go, I have no idea on how to get other information especially since each user can have multiple entries. How do I get around combining all of that?

```
def rw_file_opener (which_file):
    # if & elif statement, where the specified file will be opened
    if which_file == "user_info":

        user_info = open("user.txt", "r+")

        return user_info

    elif which_file == "tasks_info":

        task_info = open("tasks.txt", "r+")

        return task_info

tasks = rw_file_opener("tasks_info") #Opening a file with tasks and username

users = rw_file_opener("user_info") #Opening a file with usernames and passwords

#Counting the number of users registered
user_count = 0

for no_of_users in users:

    user_count += 1

#Counting the number of tasks registered
task_count = 0

for no_of_tasks in tasks:

    task_count += 1

# Printing the infomation in a user friendly manner
print(f"The Total number of tasks generated is: {task_count}")

print(f"The Total number of users registered is: {user_count}")

print("")

tasks.seek(0)

# Figuring out how many tasks each user has

names = []

from collections import Counter

for element in tasks:

    task_split = element.split(", ")
    
    task_username = task_split[0]
    
    task_status = task_split[5]
    
    names.append(task_username)
    
    names_dictionary = Counter(names)

# Presenting the information in an easy to read manner
for key, value in names_dictionary.items():

    print(f'''Username: {key}
Total number of tasks: {value}''')
    
    perc = value/task_count*100 # Calculating the percentage of the total number of tasks for each user
    
    print(f'''The percentage of the total number of tasks: {perc}
''')
```

I really am stuck if someone can please help, I am new to code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that helps you started (loading data from the file and printing some info):

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Load data:
data = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        username, title, desc, issued, due, status = [
            l.strip() for l in line.split(",")
        ]
        data.append(
            {
                "username": username,
                "title": title,
                "desc": desc,
                "issued": datetime.strptime(issued, "%d %b %Y"),
                "due": datetime.strptime(due, "%d %b %Y"),
                "status": status,
            }
        )

# 1. total number of registered users (assuming usernames are unique)
num = len(set(d["username"] for d in data))
print("Total number of registered users:", num)

# 2. total number of tasks (assuming task titles are unique)
num = len(set(d["title"] for d in data))
print("Total number of tasks:", num)

# 3. the total number of tasks assigned to that user:
tmp = {}
for d in data:
    tmp.setdefault(d["username"], []).append(d["title"])

for user in tmp:
    print("Total tasks assigned to user {} is {}".format(user, len(tmp[user])))

# 4. What percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to that user?
total_tasks = len(set(d["title"] for d in data))

for user in tmp:
    print(
        "percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to user {} is {:.2f}%".format(
            user, (len(tmp[user]) / total_tasks) * 100
        )
    )

# ...
```

Prints:

```
Total number of registered users: 3
Total number of tasks: 3
Total tasks assigned to user Makaviwe is 1
Total tasks assigned to user Sanele is 2
Total tasks assigned to user Aphelele is 1
percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to user Makaviwe is 33.33%
percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to user Sanele is 66.67%
percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to user Aphelele is 33.33%
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, Everything else can be unique but the username is not, I mean for example Andrej can have more than one task assigned to them, will this still work?

Comment: @snlonline Yes of course. In my example I print `Total tasks assigned to user Sanele is 2` so there can be multiple tasks assigned to one name

Comment: Ah I see, I will take a look at the code and see how it all works, hopeful I can be able to answer other questions, again thank you so much

Comment: I must say I'm even more confused now. The code is full of functions I've never seen before or learnt yet, trying to understand their documentation not having much luck

Comment: Also the output layout isn't exactly ideal for large number of users. My layout would be preferable.

Comment: Ow in tmp I can just change the 'tittle' to any information that I need at that time and it will simply create a list of items belonging to that user?